# How to assemble cohort using data from 2 separate tables PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to assemble a cohort of patients who meet a set of certain criteria (using data from 2 different tables). I am trying to create a list of patients who

1. Have been seen for a drug overdose
2. Encounter occur after 07-15-1999
3. Age is between 18 and 35 at the time of the encounter

Every patient in this table must meet all of these conditions. I have created a new table (dcohort) to insert the information for all of these patients. I have already figured out how to determine which patients meet the first two conditions, but am struggling to figure which meet the age condition because age is not a listed element in either of the 2 provided tables. Age must be calculated using the birthdate from one table (patients) and the encounter date from another other table (encounters). I want to know how to go about altering my code below to filter for patients who meet the age requirement. The code I have written thus far is:

```
CREATE TABLE dcohort (
    PATIENT_ID                VARCHAR(50) NULL
    ,ENCOUNTER_ID             VARCHAR(50) NULL
    ,HOSPITAL_ENCOUNTER_DATE  DATE NULL   
    ,AGE_AT_VISIT         NUMERIC(2,0) NULL
    ,DEATH_AT_VISIT_IND   BIT NULL
    ,COUNT_CURRENT_MEDS   NUMERIC(2,0) NULL
    ,CURRENT_OPIOID_IND   BIT NULL
    ,READMISSION_90_DAY_IND   BIT NULL
    ,READMISSION_30_DAY_IND   BIT NULL
    ,FIRST_READMISSION_DATE   DATE NULL
);
----------

INSERT INTO dcohort (patient_id, encounter_id, hospital_encounter_date, age_at_visit)
SELECT encounters.patient, encounters.encounterid, encounters.start, [placeholder]    
FROM encounters
JOIN patients
    ON encounters.patient = patients.id
    WHERE reasondescription = 'Drug overdose'
        AND start > '1999-7-15'
```

Comment: Show the layout of the data you are starting with.

Comment: You shouldn't store the age to begin with. It's extremely easy (and cheap) to calculate it on the fly - e.g. using the `age()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be starting with something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.patient) e.patient, e.encounterid, e.start, 
       age(p.birthdate, e.start) 
FROM encounters e JOIN
     patients p
     ON e.patient = p.id
WHERE e.start > '1999-07-15' AND
      e.reasondescription = 'Drug overdose' AND
      e.start >= p.birthdate + interval '18 year' AND
      e.start < p.birthdate + interval '36 year'
ORDER BY e.patient, e.start;
```

This uses `DISTINCT ON` to get only one record per patient -- regardless of the number of eligible encounters that the patent has.

Note that this does not use `age()` to calculate the age.  Instead, it uses direct comparisons between the dates.  That is usually more accurate.

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot! However, whenever I try to insert these values into the cohort table, it says that the age cannot be inserted because my column is of type numeric but the values are of type interval.

Comment: I just need the age value (no need for months/days) and I need it to be of type numeric

Comment: @Nexpert101 . . . You an extract the year from age:  `extract(year from age())`.